# Is it possible to retrieve all posts/comments in facebook that contains certain string with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have tried this using FQL, however it needs at least one indexable fields and restricts me to search only one page/user/post. This is possible in twitter api using search/tweets and I really want to know whether it is possible to do the same with Facebook Graph API and how.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Twitter can index the complete tweets (limited length) and allow you to do a search but it becomes very difficult for facebook because of the amount of data.

Comment: This is not possible.